# Texture2D Array as Render Target in HLSL Pixel Shader

Tags: arrays, textures, hlsl, texture2d, pixel-shader

Currently I need a couple of textures' worth of per-pixel data from my rendering pass (normals, depth and colour).

Instead of running three passes with shaders that are essentially the same (WorldViewPos multiplication, etc.) but each outputting a different type of data to a texture in a render target (e.g. one pass for colour, one pass for depth, one pass for normals); I'd like to either use a Texture3D object or ideally a Texture2D array as my pixel shader's render target. That way I could reduce these three render passes to just one and output all the data in one go.

Unfortunately the only examples I've found have been for geometry shaders. Is there a way to specify which texture in a texture array to send data to inside a pixel shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Multiple Render Targets".

You can set more than one render target using `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTargets` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.setrendertargets.aspx), [see also](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)).

You can output to multiple render targets in a HLSL pixel shader by outputting to `COLOR0` (the [semantic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx)) for the first target, `COLOR1` for the second, and so on.

Finally, you must be using the [HiDef](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx) profile, which allows up to 4 render targets to be set at once.

---

EDIT: I just realised I gave an XNA answer - but actually you didn't tag the question with an API at all. The HLSL should be the same for DirectX, SlimDX, etc. To set render targets in DirectX I think you want 
`IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderTarget` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174455(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for that, it's just what I needed, but I've been having problems with the implementation. I started a new question for it as I've had to paste a fair amount of data in order to elabourate. It can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891194/multiple-render-targets-not-saving-data